# .NET How to keep a Threading.Task alive with a While Loop

Tags: .net, multithreading, infinite-loop, cancellationtokensource

I have no previous experience with Windows's DebugDiag and need some insight about this report.

My EWS Managed API application spans a new task evertytime an event occurs.

My app runs on ~30-35% CPU usage so I decided to run this diagnostic tool to find out the wheres and whys.

I got this and need to make sure what I see is right what I think it is.

Judging from the picture below it says that the `Task.StartNew` function was executed 5 times and that caused this high CPU usage?

**Update**

After looking deeper I found what appears to be the "Stacktrace" with some function calls highlighted in Red, I have a feeling red means these functions cause the high CPU, and these functions appear to be comming from EWS Managed API code.

[image: Analysis Report]

[image]

Comment: The top of the call stack is an Exchange task which synchronizes the data. So that high CPU usage can be expected, and will end when data sync finishes. If you know how to use a tool such as ILSpy you can decompile the related methods to gain more insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the CPU eating piece of code.

I had an infinite while loop inside the Tast because I needed to keep it from being garbage collected.

```
        While Not pToken.IsCancellationRequested
            If pToken.IsCancellationRequested Then Return
        End While
```

This caused my CPU usage to go high 38% all the time!

So instead I used

```
        _CancelSignal = New AutoResetEvent(False)

        _CancelSignal.WaitOne()
```

To put the thread to sleep until I tell it to exit by setting the `_CancelSignsal`

Comment: To re-create the behavior you really should use a `ManualResetEvent`. The auto event will reset itself after it lets one thing through, your old code would let more than one thing through once the cancellation was requrested